# Why does session end after browser app closes only on mobile

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I have an MVC built website that uses Identity authentication. Logging in, closing the browser, reopening the browser and remaining logged in work fine on my desktop browsers (tried on chrome and firefox), however if I'm on my mobile (for example using an iphone with safari) and on the website, the moment I kill the safari app and reopen the app, I'm prompted for login.

Is there something different with mobile browsers that I need to account for?

Comment: Is your Mobile Safari in Private mode? (i.e. is the address bar black?) or does it have settings configured to not preserve cookies? Have you tried it on other phones? (iOS Safari does not make it obvious that you're in Private Mode - especially since Non-Private Dark Mode in iOS 13 looks identical to Private Mode in iOS 12 - in iOS 13 they changed it so that only the address bar has a black background - it's too subtle, imo).

Comment: Is it the same for other websites?

Comment: It’s only happening to my website. And it’s not in private mode. I’ve tried safari and firefox app. Really puzzling as it isn’t happening when I access the website via desktop. I tried on another iPhone and it’s also happening.